# javascript equivalent to jquery closest().find()

Tags: javascript

```
<tr>
    <td><input type="text" class="rate" oninput="priceChanged(this)"> </td>
    <td><input type="text" class="quantity"></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="total"> </td>
</tr>
```

I can find the quantity textbox with jquery-

```
var quantityTextbox = $('.rate').closest('tr').find('.quantity');
```

I would like to do it now with pure javascript.

I am newcomer in the pure javascript world.
Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `querySelector` & [`.closest()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest) for this like:

```js
var quantityTextbox = document.querySelector('.rate').closest('tr').querySelector('.quantity')
console.log(quantityTextbox.value)
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="text" class="rate" oninput="priceChanged(this)"> </td>
    <td><input type="text" class="quantity" value="10"></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="total"> </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

---

If you are calling this inside `priceChanged()` function, then you can use:

```
function priceChanged(rate){
    var quantityTextbox = rate.closest('tr').querySelector('.quantity')
}
```

as you are already passing `this` inside `priceChanged()` function.

```js
function priceChanged(rate) {
  var quantityTextbox = rate.closest('tr').querySelector('.quantity')
  console.log(quantityTextbox.value)
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="text" class="rate" oninput="priceChanged(this)"> </td>
    <td><input type="text" class="quantity" value="10"></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="total"> </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```